# JVM class Loader can not load custom jar from extension class path

Tags: java, jvm

I am studying the jvm class loading process,and got know the following fact:

**the Class Loader Subsystem uses a delegation hierarchy algorithm
It will search in order from BootStrap path --> extension path-->Application path.**

Then I want to "try" this in real code as below :

create a class A, and Class B; Class A with the main() method and a type B variable.

after compiling , I used jar command to get jar file of Class B from B.class, then delete the B.class file, put the B.jar file to jdk/jre/lib/ext
(Since the oracle doc says the extClassLoader will not search any loose classfile in jdk/jre/lib/ext).

The result is ClassNotFoundException .so My question is :

1) Does jvm not allow loading of user's clasfile from BootStrap and Extension classpath ?

2) if so , why its loading using a delegation hierarchy algorithm which seems to result in low efficiency ?

tks ....

Comment: JVM use ExtensionClassLoader to load your own jar package.so you can try to use this calssLoader to load the class and see what happen actually.

Answer (score 0):

Things seem bit strange.

After several times of ClassNotFoundException , I got java.lang.IllegalAccessError which at least indicates the extclassloader is trying to access my class B.jar

since I did not declare a package for Class A and B, This might be the reason, so I just added a public modifier before my Class B and did the same as above , finally the ExtClassLoader works withs my B.jar.

though still no idea why first times the jvm ignores my jar file and later on read it ....seems jvm keeps a catche of directory list(of BootStrap and Ext class path)which does not update just-in-time like my computer system

Comment: This doesn't appear to be answer to your own question. I would add this to the question.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are doing something wrong in your deployment.

I have used `lib/endorsed`in the past without problem even for internal `java.lang*` classes.

The JVM doesn't cache anything from one run to the next.